# Selected and url parameters

Tags: php, selected

I want my `li` menu link to be selected when I'm on `www.example.com/folder1/?page=1`

And it works when I have:

```
$current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo ($current_page == '/folder1/' || isset($_GET['page'])) ? ' class="selected"' : '';
```

But I also have page like: `www.example.com/folder2/?page=1` and when I'm on `folder1` or `folder2` page and `$_GET['page']` is set, both `li` menu links are selected, I want only one to be selected.

How can I have selected only one `li` link when `$_GET['page']` is set?

Comment: have you tried to use the logical AND operator instead of OR

Comment: Can you post how you're creating this menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant way by any stretch, but here's a fix for your routine.

```
preg_match("/\/(.+?)(\/(.+?))?$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $m);
$current_page = !empty($m[1]) ? $m[1] : '';

echo $current_page == 'folder1' ? ' class="selected"' : '';
```

Comment: This works, but how can I make it work if I have subfolder in url? `echo $current_page == 'folder1/subfolder' ? ' class="selected"' : '';`